# Funcion que reciba como parametro un template C++

Tags: c++, array, template

estoy realizando un proyecto en C++ y tengo una clase llamada DataContext donde tendre como datos miembro vectores que almacenen objetos de otra clase. Quiero realizar una funcion que resiba un vector de cualquir tipo de clase para poder agregar, buscar, eliminar o modificar los objetos pertenecientes a dicho vector.

```
class DataContext
{
    private:
        vector<TarjetaCredito> listaTarjetas = vector<TarjetaCredito>();
        vector<Contrato> lvector<Contrato> listaContrato = vector<Contrato>();
    public:
        DataContext();
        virtual ~DataContext();
        static bool Create(vector<vector_de _cualquier_clase>);//METODO QUE QUIERO IMPLIMENTAR.
};
```

Pense que al momento de pasar el vector como argumento, en donde va el tipo de dato del vector tenga que poner un template, si eso es correcto, donde lo pondria?

Espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Dado que la plantilla es a nivel de la función miembro, es decir, no afecta a la clase, lo normal es dejar solo esa función como plantilla:

```
class DataContext
{
  private:
    vector<TarjetaCredito> listaTarjetas = vector<TarjetaCredito>();
    vector<Contrato> lvector<Contrato> listaContrato = vector<Contrato>();
  public:
    DataContext();
    virtual ~DataContext();

    template<class T>
    static bool Create(vector<T> &);
};
```

Dado que comentas que uno de los objetivos de la función es modificar el vector, pasa a ser una necesidad el que la función reciba una referencia a dicho vector.